# Finding all values in an array that match a given string with placeholder characters?

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, match

I have an array of strings, and when the user enters a string with question marks replacing some characters, I want the program to return all words from the array that it could be.

```
possibleWords = ["Animal", "Basket", "Bridge", "Guitar", "Needle", "Office", "Orange"]

#and the user enters "O????e", the program would return "Office" and "Orange"
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in one line using list comprehension and `all()`:

```
possibleWords = ["Animal", "Basket", "Bridge", "Guitar", "Needle", "Office", "Orange"]
m = "O????e"

result = [i for i in possibleWords if all(k=='?' or j==k  for j,k in zip(i,m))]
```

the output(`result`) will be:

```
In [4]: [i for i in possibleWords if all(k=='?' or j==k  for j,k in zip(i,m))]
Out[4]: ['Office', 'Orange']
```

also you can read about `all()` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_all.asp).

Note that this will not check the length of the words, I assume that the input length is equal to the all of items in the list. but if not, you can use `zip_logest` from `itertools` like this:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

result = [i for i in possibleWords if all(k=='?' or j==k  for j,k in zip_longest(i,m))]
```

Comment: I was going to answer this question, but nothing I would have made would have been as sleek or concise as this answer. I have to learn more about zips

Comment: This works flawlessly and is incredibly concise! Thanks!
Just a question, how does the " k=='?' or j==k  for j " part work?

Comment: @BlackNinja745Studios it will be true whether `k` is `?` or equal to the same index of the word... check zip and zip_longest docs.

Comment: Thanks, I was having trouble figuring out what it does. After reading how zip works it makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

The regex character you're looking for is ".", instead of "?". So by simple replacing the question marks with dots, you can use the regex module `re` to get your desired output:

```
import re

possibleWords = ["Animal", "Basket", "Bridge", "Guitar", "Needle", "Office", "Orange"]
entry = "O????e"

pattern = entry.replace("?", ".")
r = re.compile(pattern)
l = list(filter(r.match, possibleWords))

print(l)
```

Out:

```
['Office', 'Orange']
```